# Xfce's clock is slow to update after waking from suspend, is this normal?

Tags: linux, xfce, xubuntu, xfce4, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running Xubuntu 20.04, which I believe puts me on Xfce 4.14. This issue has got me in to some trouble when I return to my machine and contact people whilst having a completely wrong idea of what time it is. The issue can be triggered as follows:

- Take a note of the time as reported by the panel's clock and suspend to RAM before it changes.
- Wait a while. I typically leave for hours, but I presume that a few minutes is sufficient.
- Wake the machine and log back in.
- Look at the time, it will still be stuck at what it was when you left.
- I suspect that the time doesn't change until you hit the end of the current minute. For example, if you leave at 8:30:45 and come back at 9:30:20, I suspect that it will take 40 seconds to update to 9:31.

Is this a known bug with known fixes?

Comment: See this possible [solution](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12229).

Comment: @harrymc That link in of itself is an answer to my "is this normal?" question. Hopefully the devs know about it. Post your link and a similar one as an answer and I'll accept regardless of if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not alone with this problem. The post
[xfce4-panel 4.13.3 panel clock update after suspend](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12229)
from 2018 deals with the same problem, where the `clock` plugin was not
programmed to refresh itself.

The solution that was worked out by the participants to force refresh was:

- Get the name of the plugin: Hover over the plugin in Panel Properties Items tab
  to get its name (e.g. clock-7). Replace "clock" with "plugin".
- Find this plugin in `xfce4-settings-editor`, xfce4-panel channel under
  the plugins branch.
  There should be an associated format settings (e.g. digital-format)
  with a value (e.g. %r).
- Format an xfconf-query command to write to this channel with the same data.
  For the example, it would be:

  ```
    xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /plugins/plugin-8/digital-format -r && xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /plugins/plugin-8/digital-format -n -t string -s %I:%M\ %p
  ```
- Test by leaving the command ready in a terminal window and suspending the computer.
  Wait a few minutes and resume, and immediately run the command to see if the clock
  refreshes itself.
- If it works, add running this command (with the proper X/DBUS variables exported)
  to the resume hooks.
  Created an executable file `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/xfclock.sh` (location may vary)
  containing:

  ```
    #!/bin/bash
    case $1 in
        post)
            su rich -c "
            DISPLAY=:0
            xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /plugins/plugin-8/digital-format -r && xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /plugins/plugin-8/digital-format -n -t string -s %I:%M\ %p"
            ;;
    esac
  ```

Comment: Warning: In step 3, "write to this channel with the same data" means that you need to edit the parameters to match those that you found in step 2. I tested this without that edit and it completely changed the format of my clock. Even when I changed my settings back to what they were and redid it properly, copy and pasting %a %d %b, %R didn't give the intended results. They needed to be quoted with ''.

Comment: _"If it works, add running this command (with the proper X/DBUS variables exported) to the resume hooks"_ Should I know what this means without a link explaining it?

Comment: I don't have your environment, but if the solution works without it, then you may ignore this part. Otherwise, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505266/how-to-set-the-enviroment-variables-of-the-session-dbus-when-starting-in-an-init) might clarify something. Since you are actually implementing this process, please edit my answer to make it as accurate as possible, for improving this post for future readers.